# "Error: No default engine was specified" - Only sending json

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I keep getting this error, and I don't understand why. I am not running res.render anywhere, and I have no view engine specified (do not need one), I am doing all my routing from the front end with Angular.

Here I am making a simple request for the logged in user:

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('adminController',
  ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/user')
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.user = response.data;
      });
}]);
```

And on the backend, here is the route that only returns json:

**api.js**

```
router.get('/api/user', function(req, res) {
    var session = req.session;
    var user = db.User.findById(session.passport.user, function(err, user){
        console.log(user);
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

In my browser console, I am getting errors saying
`Cannot GET http://localhost:3000/api/user 500 (Internal Server Error)`, and my CLI is saying `No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`

Why, if I am only returning json, is express asking for a view engine?

Comment: You can set : app.set('view engine', 'html'); or app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Comment: show us the server script.

Comment: gyc: Can you be more specific? Sorry. New to node.

Comment: Found the error... turns out there was a nested res.render deep in my error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can set view engine by :

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

or

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```